# Modal queda por debajo de la sombra

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap, ionic

Estoy trabajando en `Ionic 6`/`Angular` y usando `Bootstrap 4`.

Cree una barra lateral que desde ahí se activan los distintos Modal que manejaré. Pero haciendo la primera prueba el modal me está fallando. Intenté unos cuantos `z-index` en el contenedor del contenido-item porque vi algunas soluciones para este problema pero de momento no me resultó.

Así es como me queda al ejecutar el modal desde la opción estimulos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí mi código.

```css
*{
  padding: 0px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


nav{
  width: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #1C1E57;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width 0.2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: width 0.2s linear;
  -ms-transition: width 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: width 0.2s linear;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  z-index: 999;
}
ul{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F1F1F1;
}
a{
  position: relative;
  color: #F1F1F1;
  display: table;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.fas{
  position: relative;
  width: 70px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 14px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav-item{
  position: relative;
  top: 12px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
a:hover{
  color: #00013A;
  background: #D6DE84;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav:hover{
  width: 280px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}




.contenedor{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.contenedor-grid{
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(20, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
  'sid cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot'
  'sid cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot'
  'sid cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot'
  'sid cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot'
  'sid cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot'
  'sid cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot'
  'sid cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot'
  'sid cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot'
  'sid cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot'
  'sid cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot cot';
}

.sid{
  grid-area: sid;
}
.sidebar{
  height: 100vh;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  position:fixed;
  top: 0;
}




.contenido{
  grid-area: cot;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

  padding: 10px;

  background: red;
}
.contenido-item{
  width: 100%;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.contenido-item img{
  height: 100%;
  object-fit:cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<app-header3></app-header3>

<ion-content>
  <div class="contenedor">
    <div class="contenedor-grid">

      <!-- ============================================================== -->
      <!-- Sidebar -->
      <!-- ============================================================== -->
      <div class="sid">
        <nav class="sidebar">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
                <span href="#" class="nav-item">Inicio</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
                <span href="#" class="nav-item">Ofrece</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
                <span href="#" class="nav-item">Actividad</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
                <span href="#" class="nav-item">Instrucción</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
                <span href="#" class="nav-item">Recomendaciones</span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#EstimulosModalCenter">
                <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
                <span href="#" class="nav-item">Estimulos</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
                <span href="#" class="nav-item">Guias</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
                <span href="#" class="nav-item">Materiales</span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>

      <!-- ============================================================== -->
      <!-- Contenido -->
      <!-- ============================================================== -->
      <div class="contenido">

        <div class="contenido-item">
          <img src="https://this-person-does-not-exist.com/img/avatar-gen11a536c34827c13629864202b1db9d7c.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <!-- ============================================================== -->
        <!-- Modal - Estimulos -->
        <!-- ============================================================== -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="EstimulosModalCenter" tabindex="-1" >
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-xl" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                ...
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: ¿Dónde le estás poniendo estilos a ese modal, como para que intentaras usar z-index?

Comment: @Alfabravo Usando el Id del modal. Pero no es código que me funcionara por eso lo quite del css.

Comment: La _mala_ noticia es que el código que tienes en la pregunta, ejecutado acá a pantalla completa, muestra el modal exactamente como dices que quieres

Comment: @Alfabravo Cierto. Bueno, toca analizar div por div.

Answer (score 0):

Te ocurre por el `z-index`, donde tienes un valor muy alto.
Utiliza por ejemplo

```
z-index=2
```